# How to make many variables look neater php

Tags: php, variables

I have a form on a website in which when the page is loaded, it gets all the values for the fields from a database, but when they click submit and the required fields are not filled out, it throws them back and all the data they changed is now reverted to the previous state as if they hadn't touched it at all.

I have decided to put it in variables where if the submit button hasnt been clicked, the variable is the result from the database, but if it has been clicked the variable is the $_POST of the form that has been "submitted".

My question is, how do I make this look "neater" in the code as currently its just 20+ variables, defined twice, in an if statement:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $jobtitle = $record['job_title'];
        $sitecontact = $record['site_contact'];
        $siteph = $record['site_phno'];
        $siteadd = $record['site_add'];
        $sitesuburb = $record['site_suburb'];
        $sitepc = $record['site_pc'];
        $jobref = $record['job_ref'];
        $quoteref = $record['quote_ref'];
        $systembrand = $record['cctv_alarm_brand'];
        $jobtype = $record['job_type'];
        $datebooked = $record['date_booked'];
        [...]
    }else{
        $jobtitle = $_POST['title'];
        $sitecontact = $_POST['cname'];
        $siteph = $_POST['cnum'];
        $siteadd = $_POST['address'];
        $sitesuburb = $_POST['suburb'];
        $sitepc = $_POST['postcode'];
        $jobref = $_POST['jobref'];
        $quoteref = $_POST['quoteref'];
        $systembrand = $_POST['brand'];
        $jobtype = $_POST['job_type'];
        $datebooked = $_POST['date'];
        $timebooked = $_POST['time'];
        [...]
    }
```

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use an array. On that note, `$_POST` is an array already - why not use that?

Comment: some consistency in your naming conventions would probably help. `datebooked`, `date`, and `date_booked` shouldn't all be named differently.

Comment: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) maybe?

Comment: You should also sanitize your user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Change the name of the variables so they use the same column names in your database. This will make your code less confusing too in the future for others and for yourself.
2. Import variables used in the array using [extract()](http://php.net/extract).

Code:

```
// turn $record['name'] to $name. be careful because this will overwrite variables
extract($record);
$jobtitle = $jobtitle ?: $_POST['jobtitle'];
```

Comment: `$jobtitle = $jobtitle ?: $_POST['jobtitle'];` What does the `?:` do?

Comment: it's called a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). it's a shorthand if/else statement.

Comment: After reading into it a bit further, wouldn't I need to do something like `$jobtitle = (!isset($_POST['submit'])) ? $jobtitle : $_POST['jobtitle'];`

Answer (score 0):

Use operator ?

> If Condition is true ? then value X : otherwise value Y

```
$jobtitle = (isset($_POST['submit'])) ? $_POST['title'] : $record['job_title'];
[...]
```